# Proper way to bind in tree structure with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, binding

So I have the following "target/goal"-structure:

```html
<p data-bind="text: Title" class="commentContent">
  <a class="removeComment" data-bind="attr: {'data-commentId':Id}">x</a>
</p>
```

The anchor tag has to be in the paragraph. Now, as you can imaginge, the anchor tag is overwritten by the paragraph content.

What's the proper way to bind such stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do that, using the containerless syntax to avoid extra DOM cluttering your page:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ Title: "My fancy title", Id: 42 });
```

```css
.commentContent { background: lime; padding: 10px; }
a { color: red; font-weight: bold; background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p class="commentContent">
  <!-- ko text: Title --><!-- /ko -->
  <a class="removeComment" data-bind="attr: {'data-commentId':Id}">XanchorX</a>
</p>
```

You could also not use the containerless syntax, but use a `span` with a specific `class` instead, if you do need the extra markup to target it with certain CSS.

Comment: Holy guacamole! How could I miss 2 approaches?!
Btw, what do you think of containerless? Somehow I don't like it because it's very inconsistent...

Comment: I tend to user an element when possible, because it usually "makes sense", e.g. in your scenario you'll probably need the element at some point anyhow to target the post title with some css. But containerless has its uses, for example inside `option` elements where no other elements are allowed.

Comment: Makes sense!
I used span-tags now. :)